# Is it possible to make the div the same height as images in a row in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the "row" class from bootstrap and I have two images and a div which contains some text.  Here is an example here: http://notionfresh.com/testsite/

My aim is to make all the elements in the row the same height.  Is there any way I can achieve this using in the given example?

```css
.colly {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.colly2 {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
   
.pclass {
 padding: 20px;
}

.textbox {
 height: auto;
    min-width: 270px;
    background: #000;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-style: oblique;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Portfolio</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <!-- Bootstrap -->
 <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.7.1/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.7.1/js/lightbox.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="colly col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <a href="img/portfolio_2.png" ><img src="img/portfolio_2.png" class="img-responsive img-home-portfolio"/></a>
          </div>
          <div class="colly col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <a href="img/portfolio_3.png" ><img src="img/portfolio_3.png" class="img-responsive img-home-portfolio"/></a>
          </div>
          <div class="colly2 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="textbox">
    <p class="pclass">Sed cursus libero a risus molestie, vitae lobortis mi aliquam. Curabitur euismod velit risus, et scelerisque elit rhoncus quis. Integer semper lorem quis nisl viverra, nec egestas massa rhoncus. In vitae eros accumsan, commodo tellus at, volutpat neque. Sed rutrum, justo quis congue dictum, odio risus imperdiet nunc, sit amet laoreet nibh ex id tortor. Proin a pretium ipsum. Ut fermentum urna at lobortis interdum.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
        </div><!-- /.row -->
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i think you want to make black box same size as image. you can set height for textbox class and min-height for colly2 class.

Comment: You will have to use flexbox but that may interfere with some of the bootstrap classes (really depends on your use). Or use JQuery to add CSS classes to the element.